# deserialization of a JSON API response with moshi

Tags: json, retrofit2, json-deserialization, json-api, moshi

I got a `null` object attributes after deserialization of a `json` response.
Developing under android, I'm using `retrofit2` , moshi as converter (https://github.com/kamikat/moshi-jsonapi ) .
When debugging ,I saw a `json` response fully retrieved (not null attributes),but deserialization fails. Should I use `GSON` instead?

Here's my retrofit builder I use to make my `json` call: (no issue)

```
public static JsonServerInterface getSimpleClient(){

     Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_AUTH_URL)a
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
   JsonServerInterface webServer=retrofit.create(JsonServerInterface.class);
   return webServer;     
}
```

My `api` `json` call,response contain  `UserModel` with `null` attributes(deserialization fails without any error)

```
signInCall.enqueue(new Callback<UserModel>(){
  @Override
  public void onResponse
  (Call<UserModel> call, Response<UserModel> response)
  {
    response.message();
  }
}
```

My `UserModel` (as required by moshi ,but I think it lacks something):

```
@JsonApi(type = "users")
public class UserModel extends Resource {

@Json(name = "auth-token")
private String authToken;
@Json(name = "firstname")
private String firstname;
@Json(name = "lastname")
private String lastname;
@Json(name = "email")
private String email;
@Json(name = "created-at")
private String createdAt;
@Json(name = "updated-at")
private String updatedAt;

private HasMany<ActivityModel> activities;
```

My `json` response I saw when debugging http response, I retrieve without any trouve,but moshi sucks to deserialize it,and no errors are raised:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "21",
        "type": "users",
        "attributes": {
            "auth-token": "t8S3BTqyPwN3T4QDMY1FwEMF",
            "firstname": "aymen",
            "lastname": "myself",
            "email": "aymen.myself@gmail.com",
            "created-at": "2017-11-13T22:52:39.477Z",
            "updated-at": "2017-11-13T23:21:09.706Z"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "activities": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": "81",
                        "type": "activities"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "included": [
        {
            "id": "81",
            "type": "activities",
            "attributes": {
                "title": "activity 10",
                "description": "how to draw a circle",
                "start-at": "2017-11-13T23:06:13.474Z",
                "duration": 10,
                "created-at": "2017-11-13T23:06:32.630Z",
                "updated-at": "2017-11-13T23:06:32.630Z"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "user": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": "21",
                        "type": "users"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your UserModel doesn't match that JSON structure. It matches that inner "attributes" object, though. I'd suggest starting with aligning your models' structures.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution after lot of hours:
I should use "Document" instead of UserModel

interface:

```
 @POST("sign-in.json")
    Call<Document> signIn(@Body Credentials credentials);
```

when calling:

```
   signInCall.enqueue(new Callback<Document>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Document> call, Response<Document> response) {
```

hope it helps

Comment: By using `Call<UserModel>` signature, it's required to add the extra [converter factory](https://gist.github.com/kamikat/baa7d086f932b0dc4fc3f9f02e37a485).

Comment: ah ok, thanks , I'll give it a try, why it's not included directly within moshi json api? may be it's instable?

Comment: Although it's common to use the library with Retrofit, the library itself has nothing to do with Retrofit. It's better to provide a separated module for this factory file with tests.

Comment: @kamikat I do understand ,thank you for your help , now it works fine !